# Спарсить название объявления на Авито на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Делаю парсер для авито на python, универсальный, то есть под любую категорию. Не могу спарсить название объявления. Вот код HTML на самом сайте авито:

```
<h3 class="snippet-title" data-marker="item-title" data-shape="default">
    <a class="snippet-link" itemprop="url" href="/moskva/avtomobili/bmw_5_seriya_2013_1906074802" target="_blank" title="BMW 5 серия, 2013, с пробегом, цена 1 157 000 руб. - Автомобили в Москве">BMW 5 серия, 2013</a>
```

Есть ссылка на стрницу: https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/bmw/5-seriya-ASgBAgICAkTgtg3klyjitg3UnCg?radius=0  Не могу получить название: BMW 5 серия, 2013. Эти слова не в span, как получить - не знаю. Имеется код:

```
def parse_block(self, item)
    url_block = item.select_one('a.snippet-link')
    href = url_block.get('href')
    if href:
        url = 'https://www.avito.ru' + href
    else:
        url = None

    # Выбрать блок с названием
    title_block = item.select_one('h3.snippet-title.a.snippet-link')
    print(title_block)
    return
    title = title_block.string.strip()
```

h3.snippet-title.a.snippet-link - неудачная попытка достать текст. **Подскажите пожалуйста, как достать эти слова: "BMW 5 серия, 2013" отсюда: 
`<a class="snippet-link" itemprop="url" href="/moskva/avtomobili/bmw_5_seriya_2013_1906074802" target="_blank" title="BMW 5 серия, 2013, с пробегом, цена 1 157 000 руб. - Автомобили в Москве">BMW 5 серия, 2013</a>`.**
*Заранее огромное спасибо!*

Comment: Это bs4? (....)

Comment: Вот библиотеки, которые использую: urllib.parse, from collections import namedtuple, bs4, requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вытащить все атрибуты

```
title_block.attrs
```

Ещё один из вариантов -- это поиск подстроки и всё. Ссылку достали. Предположим, она лежит в переменной `title` (вы его вроде вытащили).

```
s_anchor = 'title="'  # якорь начальной позиции
f_anchor = '">'  # якорь конечной позиции позиции
s_pos = title.find(s_anchor) + len(s_anchor) #  ищем начало title
f_pos = title[s_pos].find(f_anchor)  # ищем конечную позицию.

name = title[s_pos:f_pos]  # название, которое лежит в атрибуте
```

Answer (score 0):

Так проще:

```
title = item.find('a', class_='snippet-link')['title']
```

Где `item` Это `soup.find('div', {'itemtype': 'http://schema.org/Product'})`

Здесь полный код

```
def get_item(html):
    products = []
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # bs == from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    items = soup.find_all('div', {'itemtype': 'http://schema.org/Product'})
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('a', class_='snippet-link')['title']
        price = item.find('span', {'data-marker': 'item-price'}).text
        link = 'https://www.avito.ru' + item.find('a', class_='snippet-link')['href']
        products.append((title, price.strip(), link))
    return products
```